# Password Protected Logout Button Not Working

Tags: password

Hello Wordpress StackExchange,

I have a question regarding what I could do using the following, please review the link below which fully explains my scenario and give me some input to what I could try to remedy my Password Protected Logout Button issue?

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/logout-button-on-password-protected-page-not-working/#post-8260892

Thanks for your support,
LVFIT

Comment: Hi, I agree with the comment that you received on that forum, that your paid for support is the best way to get a solution.  There isn't enough information in your post to allow anyone else to attempt a suitable answer really.  You say a predecessor didn't leave you the support details, but if you contact your theme's authors then they should have some record that lets you re-establish contact with them.  Third party plugins and themes are off-topic here, mainly because they all require special knowledge to be able to help with problems. [ask]

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've posted to their support forums which was free and have gotten a better response to the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be marked as resolved since Studiopress Forum Support has given the needed direction on their site directly.